# Need workaround for & in url, iis7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, bad-request

I am moving old asp.net website from windows 2003 to windows 2008 R2.

Some pages have '&' in url and it works fine on 2003 but on 2008 any '&' before '?' gives 'Bad Request'.

Those pages have serious impact on website popularity, 7% of all visits start here, so it is important to handle them properly without changing url. 
Any ideas how to handle such urls on iis7 / asp.net 2.0?

PS: validateRequest doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="*,:,\" />

    ...
</system.web>
```

Notice that I have removed `&` from the list of invalid characters in a path.

Comment: Unrecognized attribute 'requestPathInvalidCharacters' :(

Comment: msdn says it is only for dotNet 4.0, I have application in 2.0

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a link](http://forums.asp.net/p/1217915/2346761.aspx#2346761) that may get you where you want to to be, but if you read the details, I'd personally add this to the "do so at your own risk" category...[take Microsoft's word for at least one of the "fixes"](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;826437):

> Important If you enable this fix, you increase the attack surface of the application. You should not enable this fix unless the application requires it.

`DWORD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET VerificationCompatibility = 1`

The others should be self-explanatory on *risk* just by the setting names (e.g. `AllowRestrictedCharacters`, `ValidateRequest=False`):

That said, you should think about updating those "legacy" urls and do a `301` Permanent redirect to account for your SEO/popularity...